# Почему не работают scenes в Telegraf js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf

В Telegraf не работает функционал сцен. Не могу понять почему не срабатывает middleware. Мой код:

```
    import { Telegraf, Scenes } from "telegraf";

    let token = 'XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    let bot = new Telegraf(token);

    let scene1 = new Scenes.BaseScene('test1');
    scene1.enter((ctx) => { console.log('Enter to Scene 1'); })
    scene1.command('test', ctx => { console.log('Test in scene 1')})
    scene1.leave(()=> { console.log('Exit scene 1')})

    let scene2 = new Scenes.BaseScene('test2');
    scene2.enter((ctx) => { console.log('Enter to Scene 2'); })
    scene2.command('test', ctx => { console.log('Test in scene 2')})
    scene2.leave(()=> { console.log('Exit scene 2')})

    let stage = new Scenes.Stage([scene1, scene2], { ttl: 10 });

    bot.use(stage.middleware());

    bot.command('lt', ctx => {
      ctx.scene.enter('test1')
    })

    bot.on('text', ctx => {
      console.log('text');
    })

    bot.launch();
```

После вызова bot.use(stage.middleware()) в переменной контекста ctx не появляется секция ctx.scene
При вызове сцены соответственно появляется ошибка:

```
ctx.scene.enter('test1')
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enter')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ку, я добавил `bot.use(session());` перед `bot.use(stage.middleware());` и заработало. Видимо, мидлвер сессии нужен, хотя нигде это не указано

Comment: в сессиях хранится состояние, поэтому да - для того чтобы использовать сцены, необходимы сессии, чтобы телеграф смог определить состояние и сооветстветствующую сцену